# Why is lsblk showing the old FSTYPE and LABEL of a device that was formatted?

Tags: linux, kernel, partition, block-device, parted

I formatted an external hard drive (sdc) to ntfs using parted, creating one primary partition (sdc1). Before formatting the device [SystemRescueCd](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Installing-SystemRescueCd-on-a-USB-stick/) was installed on the external hard drive using the command `dd` in order to be used as a bootable USB. However when listing devices with `lsblk -f` I am still getting the old FSTYPE (iso9660) and LABEL (sysrcd-5.2.2) for the formatted device (sdc):

```
NAME       FSTYPE      LABEL           UUID   MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                            
├─sda1     ntfs        System Reserved                       
├─sda2     ntfs                                               
├─sda3     ntfs                                               
├─sda4                                                                         
sdc        iso9660     sysrcd-5.2.2                     
└─sdc1     ntfs        sysrcd-5.2.2          /run/media/user/sysrcd-5.2.2
```

As shown in the output of `lsblk -f` only the FSTYPE of the partition `sdc1` is correct, the `sdc1` partition LABEL, `sdc` block device FSTYPE and LABEL are wrong. The nautilus GUI app is also showing the old device label (sysrcd-5.2.2).

After creating a new partition table, `parted` suggested I reboot the system before formatting the device to **ntfs**, but I decided to unmount sdc instead of rebooting.

- Could it be that the kernel is still using the old FSTYPE and LABEL because I haven't rebooted the system? Do I have to reboot the system to get rid of the old FSTYPE and LABEL?
- As an alternative to rebooting is there a way to rename the FSTYPE and LABEL of a block device manually so that I can change them to the original FSTYPE and LABEL that shipped with the external hard drive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the output of `lsblk -f` in the original post I suspected that the signature of the installed SystemRescueCd was still present in the external hard drive. So I ran the command `wipefs /dev/sdc` and `wipefs /dev/sdc1` which printed information about `sdc` and all partitions on `sdc`:

```
[root@fedora user]# wipefs /dev/sdc
DEVICE OFFSET TYPE    UUID                   LABEL
sdc    0x8001 iso9660                        sysrcd-5.2.2
sdc    0x1fe  dos                            
[root@fedora user]# wipefs /dev/sdc1
DEVICE OFFSET TYPE UUID             LABEL
sdc1   0x3    ntfs  
sdc1   0x1fe  dos
```

The above printout confirmed that the `iso9660` partition table created by SystemRescueCd was still present. `lsblk` was using the `TYPE` and `LABEL` of the `iso9660` partition table instead of the dos (Master Boot Record) partition table. To get `lsblk` to display the correct partition table the `iso9660` partition table had to be deleted. Note that `dd` can also be used to wipe out a partition-table signature from a block (disk) device but `dd` could also wipe out other partition tables.

Because we want to target only a particular partition-table signature for wiping, `wipefs` was preferred since unlike `dd`, with `wipefs` we would not have to recreate the partition table again. The `-a` option of the command `wipefs` erases all available signatures on the device but the `-t` option of the command `wipefs` when used together with the `-a` option restricts the erasing of signatures to only a certain type of partition table. Below we wipe the `iso9660` partition table. The `-f` (`--force`) option is required when erasing a partition-table signature on a block device.

```
[root@fedora user]# wipefs -a -t iso9660 -f /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc: 5 bytes were erased at offset 0x00008001 (iso9660): 43 44 30 30 31
```

After erasing the `iso9660` partition table we check the partition table again to confirm that the partition table `iso9660` was erased:

```
[root@fedora user]# wipefs /dev/sdc
DEVICE OFFSET TYPE UUID LABEL
sdc    0x1fe  dos       
[root@fedora user]# wipefs /dev/sdc1
DEVICE OFFSET TYPE UUID             LABEL
sdc1   0x3    ntfs 34435675G36Y4776 
sdc1   0x1fe  dos
```

But now that the problematic `iso9660` partition table has been erased `lsblk` is now using the `UUID` of the partition as the mountpoint directory name since the previously used label of the `iso9660` partition-table no longer exists:

```
NAME       FSTYPE      LABEL           UUID   MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                            
├─sda1     ntfs        System Reserved                       
├─sda2     ntfs                                               
├─sda3     ntfs                                               
├─sda4                                                                         
sdc                            
└─sdc1     ntfs        34435675G36Y4776          /run/media/user/34435675G36Y4776
```

we can check which volumes (i.e. partitions) have labels in the directory `/dev/disk/by-label` which lists all the partitions that have a label:

```
[root@fedora user]# ls -l /dev/disk/by-label
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Apr 30 19:47 'System\x20Reserved' -> ../../sda1
```

The `ntfs` file system on the partition `sda1` is the only partition that has a label

To make the directory name of the mountpoint more human readable we change the label for the `ntfs` file system on the partition `sdc1` from nothing (empty string) to a "new label". The commands for changing the label for a file system depend on the file system [1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming)[2](https://www.tecmint.com/change-modify-linux-disk-partition-label-names/). For an `ntfs` file system changing the label is done with the command `ntfslabel`:

`ntfslabel /dev/sdc1 "new-label"`

Now after changing the label on the `ntfs` file system `lsblk` uses the `"new-label"` as the name of the directory of the mountpoint:

```
NAME       FSTYPE      LABEL           UUID   MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                            
├─sda1     ntfs        System Reserved                       
├─sda2     ntfs                                               
├─sda3     ntfs                                               
├─sda4                                                                         
sdc                            
└─sdc1     ntfs        new-label          /run/media/user/new-label
```

**Notice: also that the device `sdc` no longer has a file system type and label just like all the other block devices (e.g. sda). Only partitions should have a file system type since the file system is on the partition not the device, and label since the column header `LABEL` is the file system label not the device label.**

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried re-reading the partition table (as root) ?

```
partprobe /dev/sdc
```

Comment: before running a command as root it's a good idea to know exactly what the command will do. Can you add an explanation of what `partprobe /dev/sdc` does?

Comment: I ran the command `partprobe /dev/sdc`, it didn't work

Comment: `partprobe` only instrcuts the kernel to re-read the partition table. `lsblk` doesn't use the kernel's stored idea, it reads the device directly so this could not have helped.

Comment: When using zfsonlinux, partprobe does help to get `lsblk -f` to output `zfs_member` as the filesystem type.

Comment: This didn't work for me either, even though I did a full `dd` (though over ssh and gzipped).

Comment: `partprobe` also did the job for me after I had changed a Btrfs label on Debian bullseye.

Answer (score 0):

`lsblk` is probably first inspecting the first sector to see what filesystem type the device contains, and only if nothing is found, will move on to "usual" locations for filesystem superblocks.

As iso9660 is recognizable from data in the first sector, `lsblk` doesn't look further and extracts the volume label from there as well.

Simply creating a partition table leaves most of the first sector intact, which is why you are seeing this.

You need to first wipe the first sector with e.g. `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc count=1` and then recreate the partition table. If you recreate it with the same parameters, the NTFS filesystem you created earlier should still be intact.

Comment: That makes sense, although I clearly remember parted initializing the device `sdc` with zeros which took quite a while. Shouldn't that wipe the device the same way that `dd` does? The `dd` mapage says that the option count copies only N input blocks but I don't know what that means. Why are you using `count=1`? Is it to make writing zeros faster?

Comment: The `count=1` means stop after copying 1 block (512 bytes) which is the sector size. I suspect `parted` only zeroed out the newly created partition and not the whole device.

Comment: I ran the `dd` command to wipe only the first sector and recreated the partition table. You're right that the ntfs file system still seems to be intact but `lsblk` is still showing `iso9660` as the FSTYPE and `sysrcd-5.2.2` as the LABEL. DO I need to format again to complete the process you suggested?

Comment: You may have to zero out more than just the first partition. Modern fdisk starts the first partition on sector 2048, older versions started it on sector 63. Use `fdisk -l -u /dev/sdc` to see what your layout is. I'd then zero out with `count=2048` or `count=63`. However, TBH this is just cosmetic, it shouldn't matter otherwise.

Comment: I solved the problem, see my answer. I'm sure zeroing out more than just the first partition would work but I needed a simpler way that avoids recreating the partition table

Comment: Given that `lsblk --fs` works even if you're not `root`, it's not reading anything directly.  Turns out (based on `strace`) that `lsblk` talks to `udev` to get the label, at least on 16.04; this matters when you're debugging this problem from a minimal install where changes like this don't show up without an explicit `udevadm trigger`.  That's probably not what the original questioner was dealing with, though.